# Webbrowser Javascript image encoding and resizing

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, jpeg

I'm on my way creating a mobile app using phonegap and jquery mobile. i realized huge performance issues by displaying a list of images on the device. the reason must be that those images have a quite high resolution (> 1900 px in width).

i am using javascript and want to resize and reduce the resolution of an image taken by the device's camera!

is it possible to manipulate the image data in this way or is there any library to use? 
if it is possible what one has to read and / or to do to get into the matter of image manipulation.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the images on the server side otherwise you aren't gaining anything. Using a server side language such as php you could clone the image and reduce it's size for mobile. So basically you will be retreiving mobile optimized images for mobile devices. Manipulating images on the client won't save you bandwidth and will cost extra processing.

Answer (score 1):

May this link could help you: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1178073

Instead of resizing the image you could take a smaler picture.

Comment: hmm ... well thats written in objective-c. i could write that in java too. but i want to stay platform independent!

Answer (score 1):

i found something which could be quite useful! actually this is an jpeg encoder written in javascript which can reduce the image's quality but cant scale the picture!

http://www.bytestrom.eu/de/blog/2009/1120a_jpeg_encoder_for_javascript

cu